# Why does this if statement always return True?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this code:

```
steps = 0
biggestSteps = 0
startY = 2
y = startY

def process(x):
    global steps
    steps = steps + 1
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x/2
    else:
        return (3*x)+1

while True:
    y = process(y)
    if y == 1 or y == 4:
        if steps > biggestSteps:
            biggestSteps = steps
            print("Biggest number yet: " + str(startY) + ", with " + str(steps) + " steps")
            startY += 1
            y = startY
            steps = 0
```

When I try to run this code,

```
if steps > biggestSteps:
```

will alawys return True, and it will

```
print("Biggest number yet: " + str(startY) + ", with " + str(steps) + " steps")
```

For each number, which I certainly don't want.

How do I make it so it only prints when a number has reached a highest number of steps?

EDIT:

I tried adding

```
global
```

in the while loop(Pretty sure it changes nothing)

```
steps = 0
biggestSteps = 0
startY = 2
y = startY

def process(x):
    global steps
    steps = steps + 1
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x/2
    else:
        return (3*x)+1

while True:
    global steps
    global biggestSteps
    global startY
    global y
    y = process(y)
    if y == 1 or y == 4:
        if steps > biggestSteps:
            biggestSteps = steps
            print("Biggest number yet: " + str(startY) + ", with " + str(biggestSteps) + " steps")
            startY += 1
            y = startY
            steps = 0
```

Comment: You watched that Collatz Conjecture video, didn't you? :)

Comment: You probably meant to use `global steps` inside the `while` as well

Comment: Yeah. I actually had it working in Processing.py, but I accidentaly closed it, so I tried to do it in regular python. I basicly copy-pasted code. No idea why is it not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think IDLE made a mistake when copying or something, because in

```
if steps > biggestSteps:
            biggestSteps = steps
            print("Biggest number yet: " + str(startY) + ", with " + str(biggestSteps) + " steps")
            startY += 1
            y = startY
            steps = 0
```

.

```
                startY += 1
                y = startY
```

Portion of the code must not be in this if statement.